# UrlGenerator outside Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I installed Mini framework, just for testing purposes. In that I implemented Illuminate/Routing from Laravel and now I can add routes like in Laravel. How to implement route() method with UrlGenerator class so I can call route name in blade template?

Comment: Why don't you use Lumen when you need Laravel stuff?

Comment: Long story.. I need to use Mini.. Do you know how to implement this?

Comment: Why not follow how laravel did ?

Comment: I tried but I got lost in everything